# Is there a way to create location shortcuts for navigation

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I often have to navigate to the same places with the google maps navigation. I use speech to enter the address. Is there a way to create shortcuts, which i can chose on the touchscreen to navigate to an often used places? F.e. i dond't want to enter my home address everytime, instead i want to save it as "home" and have the ability to chose that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a screen shortcut for "home" or any location you use often. Long-press on the home screen, select the Shortcuts option, and scroll down to get a Directions option. You'll be prompted for an address, which can be either specific or general. Choose car, public transit, or walking directions, ensure "Turn-by-turn navigation" is checked, and give it a short name, like "home". Now you have a shortcut which will quickly get the directions you want from wherever you are.

You can also "star" locations on the map that you use often.

You can also use contacts to quickly get addresses for navigation. Were you to have a "home" entry in your contact list, you could simply use the voice command "Navigate to home".

Comment: Great answer... wish I had done this when I got the phone! Especially directions to home address!